# Automatically document all methods of an S4 generic, using roxygen2

Tags: r, r-s4, roxygen2

I am writing an [r](/questions/tagged/r) package using [roxygen2](/questions/tagged/roxygen2) for the documentation. I am having some trouble documenting S4 methods. I have defined a generic [s4](/questions/tagged/s4) method (e.g. `myGeneric`) and few methods that implement it.

**Question**: Is there a way to automatically document all methods of a generic?

The manual solution is to add these two lines for each method (this would be for the first method in my dummy example):

```
##' @rdname myGeneric-methods
##' @aliases myGeneric,numeric,numeric,missing-method
```

Since I use a lot of methods, I have to add a lot to satisfy the R CMD check.

---

I read in Hadley's Advanced R about documenting S4 methods [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Documenting-functions.html) that one can use @genericMethods:

> Use @genericMethods in the generic documentation if you want an automated listing of all methods implemented for the generic.

I think this is not implemented in `roxygen2`, or implemented under another name. The only thing I found about the `@genericMethods` tag was in the roxygen3 github [here](https://github.com/hadley/roxygen3/blob/2650b68a71b75efa05dec4402256f6afc71a622b/R/tag-generic-methods.r), which was discontinued(?).

---

Just a dummy example, where I document only the generic and want all the implemented methods automatically listed:

```
##' @param object An object
##' @param data Numeric vector or data.frame
##' @param Fun Function. Default function is \code{sum}
##' @param ... Extra named arguments passed to FUN
##' @docType methods
##' @export 
setGeneric("myGeneric", function(object, data, FUN, ...)
           {standardGeneric ("myGeneric")} )

setMethod("myGeneric", c("numeric", "numeric", "missing"),
          function(object, data,...) { 
              myGeneric(object, data, sum,...) 
          })
setMethod("myGeneric", c("numeric", "data.frame", "missing"),
          function(object, data,...) { 
              myGeneric(object, as.vector(unlist(data), sum,...) 
          })
setMethod("myGeneric", c("numeric", "numeric", "function"),
          function(object, data, FUN,...) {
             ## Do something
          })
```

Any help will be really appreciated,

alex

Comment: I don't know any way to automatically document all methods of a generic (maybe when `@genericMethods` will be implemented). I use instead `#' @describeIn myGeneric` in front of all my specific method. This does not answer exactly your question but I think it's the only way to achieve it for the moment.

Comment: I searched in the [official GitHub repo](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen) of roxygen and didn't founded any roclet that should do this job. I think that the complete roclet list is in [/roxygen/R/rocled-rd.R](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/blob/d564939daed853988eaa72bb034536c37d7e097c/R/roclet-rd.R).

Comment: I added an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/264).

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: Updated to reflect the preferred method for the latest version of roxygen2 - march 23, 2016

Actually, you can do this a lot easier with using `@rdname` in `roxygen2` :

```
#' @param object An object
#' @param data Numeric vector or data.frame
#' @param Fun Function. Default function is \code{sum}
#' @param ... Extra named arguments passed to FUN
#' @rdname myGeneric
#' @export 
setGeneric("myGeneric", function(object, data, FUN, ...)
           {standardGeneric ("myGeneric")} )

#' @rdname myGeneric
setMethod("myGeneric", c("numeric", "numeric", "missing"),
          function(object, data,...) { 
              myGeneric(object, data, sum,...) 
          })

#' @rdname myGeneric
setMethod("myGeneric", c("numeric", "data.frame", "missing"),
          function(object, data,...) { 
              myGeneric(object, as.vector(unlist(data), sum,...) 
          })

#' @rdname myGeneric
setMethod("myGeneric", c("numeric", "numeric", "function"),
          function(object, data, FUN,...) {
             ## Do something
          })
```

Does the trick for me with roxygen2 version 5.0.1

Comment: I believe @describeIn now needs a second argument providing a description, e.g. `@describeIn myGeneric the method to do something different`, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html

Comment: @cboettig That's correct. You can just use @ rdname now to point to the Rd file where you want to add the extra method. Thank you for informing me so I could update the information